# How to pass ENV variable to build process in Docker

Tags: docker, go

Building a container for my Go application has trouble with Environment variables.

On my local machine, I can do the following:

```
export GIN_MODE=release
go build -a
```

This will compile my application in a way, where the library called GIN will notice the GIN_MODE env-variable and behave differently.

When I run the application, it will state

```
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
 - using env:   export GIN_MODE=release
 - using code:  gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
```

if this ENV-variable was not set and it will omit this warnings, if the GIN_MODE variable was set properly.

However, in Docker it won't work that way.

In my `Dockerfile` I wrote these specific code lines:

```
# Build the Go app
ENV GIN_MODE=release
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -v -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .
```

I tried also to pass the variable directly in the RUN statement:

```
RUN GIN_MODE=release CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -v -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .
```

The variable will never be visible to the `go-build` statement.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables are not compiled into the go binary. Environment variables are properties of a process that get passed down to their child processes.

Your `Dockerfile` is correctly setting the `GIN_MODE` environment variable. But this `Dockerfile` appears to be used for building the go binary, but not for running/deploying the compiled binary. Thus, you should ensure that you also set the `GIN_MODE` environment variable for the execution context of the deployed application, whether that may be in a `Dockerfile` or a `systemd` unit or whatever else happens to be the method of deployment.

---

The reason why it "worked" when you did the `go build` manually in your shell was because your shell process carried the `GIN_MODE` environment variable by way of you running `export GIN_MODE=release`, and you used the same shell to later run the application, the `GIN_MODE` environment variable was available to your application by way of being a child process from your shell.